# Thymeleaf URI template JSP equivalent

Tags: spring, jsp, thymeleaf

In JSP I used to have a table and a link to a record using this syntax:

```
<td><a href="<spring:url value="/person/${person.id}"/>">${person.id}</a></td>
```

So I could click the link on a table to move to a person's details page. I would like to achieve the same result using Thymeleaf, but not quite sure how. So my question is: what is Thymeleaf equivalent?
[image]

```
<td th:text="${trip.hrPerson}"></td>

<td><a th:href="@{/remove/trip.id}"></a>  ${trip.id}  </td>
```

First example displays static value and it's ok, second is supposed to be a link but it fails.

Comment: Share the html for the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Thymleaf` you make link as follows

```
<a th:href="@{'/person/' + $person.id}" th:text="${person.id}">My User id</a>
```